# How to avoid counting blank lines in the end of a file?

Tags: c++, counting

I have a project and I'm supposed to count the lines, words and characters in a file. My program works fine but I'm not supposed to count a blank line in the end of file if there is one.

How can I avoid counting a blank line in the end of a file if there is one? I can assume there is at most one blank line in the end of the file.

Here's the loop where I'm counting the lines:

```
int count_lines(fstream& infile) {
int counter_lines=0;
string unused;

while ( getline(infile, unused) ) {
        counter_lines++;
    }
    infile.close();
return counter_lines;
}
```

Comment: use an `if` statement to filter out blank lines... blank lines have a particular signature you can filter out of the count.

Comment: but I don't want to filter out all the blank lines. Only if there is a blank line in the end of the file (I can assume there is at most one blank line in the end)

Comment: Blank lines at the end of the document also have a unique signature. If you look at the blank line at the end of the file you can see what it does / doesn't contain and filter on that.

Comment: see [lProgram to Count No of Lines, Blank Lines](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-count-lines-blank-lines-comments/)

Comment: Here is a simple solution: read char by char and remember the last char you read. Once you've exhausted the stream, if the last char is `'\n'`, then there was a new line. Be careful of the case of an empty file.

Comment: @NeilKirk: after the first line, it's when the last *two* characters are both `'\n'` that there's a blank line at the end of the file.  If by "last char" you mean the one before the one being read then your suggestion gets closer, but if you checked only that then you'd mis-identify a single-character un-newline-terminated last line as being empty.

Answer (score 3):

Have a `bool` variable to indicate if the line read was blank, call it `lastLineWasBlank` (initialise it to false). Then each time around the loop, set it to `unused.empty()`.

When your loop finishes, if `lastLineWasBlank` is true, subtract one from the count.

You might then want to change `unused` to a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate counter for blank lines.. and discard the counter if you encounter EOF, else add it to the actual count of lines. This will discard multiple blank lines at the end of the file.